# Taking better advantage of Apache Spark ML in a calculation of additionnal values accompanying a PCA

Tags: java, apache-spark, statistics, apache-spark-mllib

I want to write an `Apache Spark` code that completes the calculation of a PCA by adding informations on global summary value of each component, higher eigen values, individual contribution to an axis, quality of a projection of an individual on an axis.

It works. And from a vector of 50 features, it calculates them (three first individual, here) :

```
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|features     |scaledFeatures                             |pca                                       |xStdCarre           |contributionIndividuelleAxe                  |qualiteProjectionIndividuAxe              |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|[100.0,100.0]|[3.665634766586407,3.156450874585141]      |[-4.823943018707778,-0.36004738290505234] |23.400060365676286  |[0.29741427723298436,0.006561249644731516]   |[0.9944600947215109,0.00553990527848926]  |
|[86.1,70.3]  |[2.711113911293206,0.8064410737434008]     |[-2.4872869831159297,-1.3468070793732898] |8.000485845427955   |[0.07906955024417166,0.09180747147437675]    |[0.773277605373604,0.22672239462639585]   |
|[67.9,69.2]  |[1.461309625945275,0.7194036737122256]     |[-1.5419971620115105,-0.5246067298266516] |2.6529674686309654  |[0.03038957477136533,0.013929481805149522]   |[0.8962624969082515,0.10373750309174866]  |
```

*Remark : the column 'features' doesn't exist anymore at the end of the process. It is removed as soon as the features are standardized. But I added this column in this example to make it more readable.*

I do this calculation using few private methods :

- One creates the initial features vector.
- A short code then standardizes it and ask Spark to calculate the PCA from it.
- Another private method calculates the higher eigen values of each component, the correlation the principal component has with the variable it summarizes, and the global quality that a principal component gives for a feature.
- A last one calculates the individual contribution of each individual in the calculation of each principal component, and how fine is projected each individual on each axis.

Because I begin with ML (from `spark-mllib`), I think I miss out some of its important abilities that could have made my code clearer, simplier. Can you give me hints of what I should have done to create a code taking a better advantage of what `Apache Spark` ML can do ?

```java
package test;

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.*;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.*;

/**
 * Analyse en composantes principales.
 */
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SparkTestApplicationGestion.class)
public class AnalyseComposantesPrincipalesIT extends AbstractStatsTest implements Serializable {
   /** Serial ID. */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 7301395393891047373L;

   /**
    * Recherche de composantes principales.
    */
   @Test
   @DisplayName("ACP : le classement des universités américaines")
   public void composantePrincipale() {
      // Créer le dataset des features (des vecteurs) :

      // features
      // [100.0,100.0]
      // [86.1,70.3]
      // [67.9,69.2] 
      // ...
      Dataset<Row> dsHiCiSCi = denseRowWithVectors(
         // Le classement (variables HiCi et SCi des universités américaines).
         d(100, 100), d(86.1, 70.3), d(67.9, 69.2), d(54.0, 65.4), d(65.9, 61.7),
         d(58.4, 50.3), d(56.5, 69.6), d(59.3, 46.5), d(50.8, 54.1), d(46.3, 65.4),
         d(57.9, 63.2), d(54.5, 65.1), d(57.4, 75.9), d(59.3, 64.6), d(56.9, 70.8),
         d(52.4, 74.1), d(52.9, 67.2), d(54.0, 59.8), d(41.3, 67.9), d(41.9, 80.9), 
         d(60.7, 77.1), d(38.5, 68.6), d(40.6, 62.2), d(39.2, 77.6), d(38.5, 63.2),

         d(44.5, 57.6), d(35.5, 38.4), d(39.2, 53.4), d(46.9, 57.0), d(41.3, 53.9),
         d(27.7, 23.2), d(46.9, 62.0), d(48.6, 67.0), d(39.9, 45.7), d(42.6, 42.7),
         d(31.4, 63.1), d(40.6, 53.3), d(46.9, 54.8), d(23.4, 54.2), d(30.6, 38.0),
         d(31.4, 51.0), d(27.7, 56.6), d(45.1, 58.0), d(46.9, 64.2), d(35.5, 48.9),
         d(25.7, 51.7), d(39.9, 44.8), d(24.6, 56.9), d(39.9, 65.6), d(37.1, 52.7));

      long n = dsHiCiSCi.count();
      int p = 2; // Deux variables.
      int nombreComposantes = 2;

      // Afficher les valeurs des universités.
      dsHiCiSCi.show((int)n, false);

      // Centrer réduire les valeurs (Standardizing).

      // scaledFeatures
      // [3.665634766586407,3.156450874585141]
      // [2.711113911293206,0.8064410737434008]
      // [1.461309625945275,0.7194036737122256]
      // ...
      StandardScaler scaler = new StandardScaler().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
         .setWithStd(true)   // Réduire
         .setWithMean(true); // Centrer

      Dataset<Row> centreReduit = scaler.fit(dsHiCiSCi).transform(dsHiCiSCi).select("scaledFeatures");

      // Faire calculer par ML les composantes principales (nombreComposantes extraites de p variables).
      //
      // scaledFeatures                            pca                                      
      // [3.665634766586407,3.156450874585141]     [-4.823943018707778,-0.36004738290505234]
      // [2.711113911293206,0.8064410737434008]    [-2.4872869831159297,-1.3468070793732898]
      // [1.461309625945275,0.7194036737122256]    [-1.5419971620115105,-0.5246067298266516]
      // ...
      PCA pcaOperationDefinition = new PCA().setInputCol("scaledFeatures").setOutputCol("pca").setK(nombreComposantes);
      Dataset<Row> composantesPrincipalesCalculees = pcaOperationDefinition.fit(centreReduit).transform(centreReduit);
      composantesPrincipalesCalculees.show((int)n, false);

      // Calculer la plus grande valeur propre de chaque composante, sa corrélation avec la variable qu'elle résume, et la qualité globale du résumé qu'elle en fait.
      //
      // valeurPropre         correlationComposanteAvecXi   qualiteResumeComposante
      // 1.5648493047635532   0.8845477106305665            0.7824246523817766
      // 0.3951506952364467   0.44449448547560555           0.19757534761822335
      Dataset<Row> valeursPropresEtQualite = valeurPropreEtQualiteGlobaleResume(pcaOperationDefinition, composantesPrincipalesCalculees.select(col("pca")), n, p);
      valeursPropresEtQualite.show(false);

      // Calculer les contributions individuelles et la qualité de la représentation de chaque individu sur chaque axe.
      //
      // xStdCarre           contributionIndividuelleAxe                  qualiteProjectionIndividuAxe
      // 23.400060365676286  [0.29741427723298436,0.006561249644731516]   [0.9944600947215109,0.00553990527848926]
      // 8.000485845427955   [0.07906955024417166,0.09180747147437675]    [0.773277605373604,0.22672239462639585]
      // 2.6529674686309654  [0.03038957477136533,0.013929481805149522]   [0.8962624969082515,0.10373750309174866]
      // ... 
      Dataset<Row> contributionsEtQualiteProjectionIndividuelles = contributionsEtQuailiteIndividuelle(composantesPrincipalesCalculees, valeursPropresEtQualite, n);
      contributionsEtQualiteProjectionIndividuelles.show((int)n, false);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer les valeurs propres (eigen values), la corrélation des composantes aux variables Xi, et la qualité globale du résumé qu'elle en donne.
    * @param pcaOperationDefinition Définition de l'opération d'ACP demandée.
    * @param pca Résultat de l'ACP.
    * @param n Nombre d'éléments dans la matrice de départ.
    * @param p Nombre de variables.
    * @return Dataset contenant les valeurs propres, la corrélation des composantes aux variables Xi, et la qualité globale du résumé de chaque composante.
    */
   private Dataset<Row> valeurPropreEtQualiteGlobaleResume(PCA pcaOperationDefinition, Dataset<Row> pca, long n, int p) {
      int nombreComposantes = pcaOperationDefinition.getK();

      double[] valeursPropres = new double[nombreComposantes];                // Plus grande valeur propre de R pour une composante.
      double[] correlationsComposantesAvecXi = new double[nombreComposantes]; // Corrélation de la composante avec Xi.
      double[] qualiteComposantes = new double[nombreComposantes];            // Qualité globale du résumé proposé par la composante.

      List<Row> enregistrements = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Row> composantesTousIndividusUniversites = pca.select(col("pca")).collectAsList();

      for(Row composantesIndividuUniversite : composantesTousIndividusUniversites) {
         for(int numeroComposante = 1; numeroComposante <= nombreComposantes; numeroComposante ++) {
            double composante = ((DenseVector)composantesIndividuUniversite.get(0)).values()[numeroComposante-1]; // Φ[numero_composante]
            valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1] += composante * composante;
         }
      }

      for(int numeroComposante = 1; numeroComposante <= nombreComposantes; numeroComposante ++) {
         valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1] = valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1] / n;

         // Calcul de la qualité du résumé de la composante : 
         correlationsComposantesAvecXi[numeroComposante-1] = sqrt(valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1]) * (1 / sqrt(p));
         qualiteComposantes[numeroComposante-1] = valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1] / p;
         Row row = RowFactory.create(valeursPropres[numeroComposante-1], correlationsComposantesAvecXi[numeroComposante-1], qualiteComposantes[numeroComposante-1]);
         enregistrements.add(row);
      }

      // Construire le dataset avec le schéma [valeurPropre (double), qualiteResumeComposante (double)]. 
      StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
         new StructField("valeurPropre", DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
         new StructField("correlationComposanteAvecXi", DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
         new StructField("qualiteResumeComposante", DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
      });

      return this.session.createDataFrame(enregistrements, schema);
   }

   /**
    * Calculer les contributions individuelles par axe et la qualité de la projection pour l'individu.
    * @param acp Individus centrés réduits et ACP.
    * @param valeursPropresEtQualitesComposantes Dataset des valeurs propres et qualité des composantes, par variable.
    * @param n Nombre d'individus.
    * @return Dataset d'ACP complété de la contribution individuelle et de la qualité des composantes.
    */
   private Dataset<Row> contributionsEtQuailiteIndividuelle(Dataset<Row> acp, Dataset<Row> valeursPropresEtQualitesComposantes, long n) {
      this.session.udf().register("xCarresCentresReduitsUDF", new UDF1<DenseVector, Double>() {
         /** Serial ID. */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         /**
          * Renvoyer la somme des x carrés centrés réduits des variables d'un individu.
          * @param individuCentreReduit Individu aux variables centrées réduites.
          */
         @Override
         public Double call(DenseVector individuCentreReduit) {
            double sommeXCarreCentresReduits = 0.0;
            double[] variablesIndividuCentreesReduites = individuCentreReduit.values();

            for(int index=0; index < individuCentreReduit.size(); index ++) {
               sommeXCarreCentresReduits += variablesIndividuCentreesReduites[index] * variablesIndividuCentreesReduites[index];  
            }

            return sommeXCarreCentresReduits;
         }
      }, DoubleType);      

      // Faire la somme, par individu, des carrés des valeurs centrées réduites x* de chaque variable se rapportant à un individu.
      Dataset<Row> ds = acp.withColumn("xStdCarre", callUDF("xCarresCentresReduitsUDF", col("scaledFeatures")));

      // Calculer les contributions individuelles par axe.
      List<Double> listeValeursPropres = valeursPropresEtQualitesComposantes.select("valeurPropre").map((MapFunction<Row, Double>)v -> v.getDouble(0), Encoders.DOUBLE()).collectAsList();      
      DenseVector valeursPropres = (DenseVector)Vectors.dense(listeValeursPropres.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray());

      this.session.udf().register("contributionIndividuelleAxe", new UDF1<DenseVector, DenseVector>() {
         /** Serial ID. */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         /**
          * Renvoyer la contribution individuelle d'un individu sur un axe.
          * @param composantes Composantes principales d'un individu.
          */
         @Override
         public DenseVector call(DenseVector composantes) {
            double[] contributions = new double[composantes.size()];

            for(int axe=1; axe <= contributions.length; axe++) {
               double composante = composantes.values()[axe-1];
               double valeurPropre = valeursPropres.values()[axe-1];

               contributions[axe-1] = ((composante * composante) / n) / valeurPropre;
            }

            return (DenseVector)Vectors.dense(contributions);
         }
      }, new VectorUDT());      

      ds = ds.withColumn("contributionIndividuelleAxe", callUDF("contributionIndividuelleAxe", col("pca")));

      // Calculer la qualité de la projection, par individu, sur les axes.
      this.session.udf().register("qualiteProjectionIndividuAxe", new UDF2<DenseVector, Double, DenseVector>() {
         /** Serial ID. */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         /**
          * Renvoyer la qualité de la projection, par individu, sur les axes.
          * @param composantes Individu aux variables centrées réduites.
          * @param xStdCarre valeurs centrées réduites, au carré, cumulées pour toutes les variables associées à l'individu.
          */
         @Override
         public DenseVector call(DenseVector composantes, Double xStdCarre) {
            double[] qualite = new double[composantes.size()];

            for(int axe=1; axe <= qualite.length; axe++) {
               double composante = composantes.values()[axe-1];
               qualite[axe-1] = (composante * composante) / xStdCarre;
            }

            return (DenseVector)Vectors.dense(qualite);
         }
      }, new VectorUDT());      

      return ds.withColumn("qualiteProjectionIndividuAxe", callUDF("qualiteProjectionIndividuAxe", col("pca"), col("xStdCarre")));
   }

   /**
    * Créer un Dataset Row par des vecteurs denses constitués à partir d'upplets de valeurs.
    * @param listeUppletsValeurs liste de n-upplets.
    * @return Dataset Dense.
    */
   private Dataset<Row> denseRowWithVectors(double[]... listeUppletsValeurs) {
      List<Row> data = new ArrayList<>();

      for(double[] upplet : listeUppletsValeurs) {
         Vector vecteur = Vectors.dense(upplet);
         data.add(RowFactory.create(vecteur));
      }

       StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
         new StructField("features", new VectorUDT(), false, Metadata.empty()),
       });

       return this.session.createDataFrame(data, schema);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer un ensemble de valeurs doubles sous la forme d'un tableau.
    * @param valeurs Valeurs.
    * @return Tableau de doubles.
    */
   private double[] d(double... valeurs) {
      return valeurs;
   }
}
```